# converted data type (varchar) still shows conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that can store text but is used to store a number (I did not make the system!) someone has put a blank value in (i.e. not content but not null) and its causing error: -

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I have reduced the issue down to the below: -

```
SELECT 
    T1.[FIELD_5], 
    ISNUMERIC(T1.[FIELD_5]), 
    NULLIF(T1.[FIELD_5],''),
    ISNULL(NULLIF(T1.[FIELD_5],''),0),
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,5),ISNULL(NULLIF(T1.[FIELD_5],''),0))
FROM  
    [MyTBL] T1 
ORDER BY
    ISNUMERIC(T1.[FIELD_5])
```

The issue data is in `[FIELD_5]`

1. I can see SQL sees a value as not numeric
2. I can see that `NULLIF` is successfully changing it to a `NULL` value
3. I can see the `ISNULL` is turning the `NULLIF` result to `0`

But the `CONVERT` on the `ISNULL` result results in the error message, I would expect it to result in 0.00000

Comment: What version of SQL server? in later version your can use TRY_PARSE

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a space or unprintable character? You are aware of the limitations of `ISNUMERIC()`?

Comment: I can't explain how it wasn't caught but I have placed an answer with the explanation `1E-07` was in there and that is seen as numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a case of better investigation was needed, I should have realised as in my opinion SQL doesn't lie its normally always user error.

I run it again without the `order by` clause and then selected the row that would have shown up after the last row that did show up (i.e. that row that caused the error).

`[FIELD_5]` contained the value `1E-07`, an infamous bad import from Excel!

What doesn't add up is why when I had the order by `ISNUMERIC` on, I did not see this value at the top of the list, only the blank values that were indeed being managed properly.

Question solved, I should have stuck investigating but I think this is worth leaving up to help other investigate in the future.

Comment: If you run `SELECT ISNUMERIC('1E-07')`, you'll see it returns `1`. `ISNUMERIC()` is notoriously tolerant when it comes to evaluating numbers. Characters like `$, +, -` are all evaluated to `1`.

Comment: >>>What doesn't add up is why when I had the order by ISNUMERIC on, I did not see this value at the top of the list, only the blank values that were indeed being managed properly.<<< isnumeric(1E-07) = 1, that's why it does not pop up when you order by isnumeric. Isnumeric does not look if you further want to cast to decimal(18,5), it just tells you if this can be converted to some numeric type, and yes, 1E-07 does. It can be converted to float

Answer (score 2):

Use `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT T1.[FIELD_5], ISNUMERIC(T1.[FIELD_5]), NULLIF(T1.[FIELD_5], ''),
       COALESCE(NULLIF(T1.[FIELD_5], ''), 0),
       TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 5), COALESCE(NULLIF(T1.[FIELD_5], ''), 0))
FROM [MyTBL] T1 
ORDER BY ISNUMERIC(T1.[FIELD_5]);
```

`try_convert()` was introduced in SQL Server 2012.  If you are using an earlier version, then you need to use a `case` expression.

(I switched `ISNULL()` to `COALESCE()` because I prefer to use ANSI standard functions where practical.)

Answer (score 0):

There is some non numeric value available you can do that check with case as below:

```
select convert(decimal(18,5), '')
```

Throws error as "Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
"

```
SELECT 
    T1.[FIELD_5], 
    ISNUMERIC(T1.[FIELD_5]), 
    NULLIF(T1.[FIELD_5],''),
    ISNULL(NULLIF(T1.[FIELD_5],''),0),
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,5), iif(isnumeric(ISNULL(T1.[FIELD_5]),'0') > 1,T1.[FIELD_5],'0')
    ISNULL(NULLIF(T1.[FIELD_5],''),0))
FROM  
    [MyTBL] T1 
ORDER BY
    ISNUMERIC(T1.[FIELD_5])
```